# inapp products not found

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am getting crazy with android inapp purchases.

I checked all SO posts I could find, checked and re-checked everything in app and console setup. I have the correct package name, I have the correct licence key, same apk uploaded and installed on device, test account setup and used as primary, even did a factory restore on device, and all the rest...

BUT to no avail: it just keeps on responding

**The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found**

Nothing in the console. Rarely been that much lost in finding the cause...

```
mPurchaseFinishedListener 
       = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
       public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) 
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d("4357", "Error purchasing: " + result);
             return;
          }      
          else  
              provideContent(purchase.getSku(),"");
          }
    };


       mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
       public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)   
       {
          if (result.isFailure()) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return;
           }
          SkuDetails test=inventory.getSkuDetails("dig5");
          if(test == null){
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOTHING!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return;
          }
          String dig5 =
                  inventory.getSkuDetails("dig5").getPrice();
          String dig6 =
                          inventory.getSkuDetails("dig6").getPrice();

          String seesolution =
              inventory.getSkuDetails("seesolution").getPrice();


           // update the UI 
       }
    };

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
           public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
              if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                 // Oh noe, there was a problem.
                 Log.d("4357", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
              }
                 // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
              //ArrayList <String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
              ArrayList <String> additionalSkuList           = new ArrayList<String>();
                additionalSkuList.add("seesolution");
                additionalSkuList.add("dig5");
                additionalSkuList.add("dig6");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
                   mQueryFinishedListener);
           }
        });
```

Comment: Did you put it on Alpha Testing and publish it?

Answer (score 0):

If the in-app item is active in your console, you have to wait some time to let the changes propagate. How long? From my experience it's between 4-10 hours. It may depend on your location.

Remember that Google Play services caches request on your device. This may be also the problem but device restart should help. You can also try this command to clear the Play services cache:

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.vending
```

Comment: So it's problem with your code. Update the question with minimal example to reproduce the problem.